# Using PHP in VMWare and Eclispe on the host. I want to see the php-page in the Eclipse-Browser. How?

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, debian

Following situ:

- VMWare running on Win7
- Debian, Apache, PHP and Squid running in VMWare

the website is located in the shared folder 'SF', so from
- debian-perspective: /mnt/hgfs/SF'
- windows-perspective: [...]/SF
my index.php is located in the sub-folder 'raffael'. So I am able to edit the website with Eclipse on Windows.

I can access index.php and properly execute it using Firefox and FoxyProxy through: http://raffael

My FoxyProxy-settings are:
IP: 192.168.0.128, Port:3128, Pattern: 'http://raffael*'

How do I have to configure Eclipse so that I can access the websie through the Eclipse-Browser instead of having to switch to Firefox all the time?

Thanks and happy new year!

Raffael

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to make any changes to get the Eclipse browser to open a page; if another browser (such as firefox) can get to it, then so can your Eclipse browser. Just plug the same URL into your address bar and go.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Eclipse to use a proxy in Preferences -> General -> Network Connections.  This is most likely a http proxy.

Could you explain *why* you need the http proxy?  I do not immediately see a need to.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I have to check the PDT-manual in detail anyway, b/c I'm somewhat confused of how to establish the connection Eclipse on the host to PHP in th VM anyway ... also referring to debugging and stuff. I am basically replicating the situation I face on my workstation.

Comment: In that case, find what the IP-adress of your Debian instance (/sbin/ifconfig -a) and then just refer to that in your Windows 7 browser without any proxy configuration at all.